# Google Cloud Storage 301 redirect

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Weird behavior of Google Cloud Storage. Bucket is configured as website.

1. When I access subdirectory with '/' (http://example.com/subfolder/) at the end it responds with 200 index.html as expected
2. When I access subdirectory without '/' (http://example.com/subfolder) it responds with 301 Moved Permanently to http://example.com/subfolder/index.html

Is there any way to avoid this redirect and respond with index.html in both cases?

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you solve it? Also it would be great to be able to learn how to make 301 redirects from deleted pages.

Comment: No I haven't found any solution

Comment: I believe that is by design and AWS S3 does the same thing.